# Uncaught ReferenceError: process not defined simple-peer Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webrtc, simple-peer

I am currently learning WebRTC and using simple-peer an npm package with React and Socket.io . And when ever I try to Call the user is display this Error

```
_stream_readable.js:529 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:529:1)
    at onEofChunk (_stream_readable.js:506:1)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:255:1)
    at Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:241:1)
    at index.js:448:1
```

My code of React Component

```
    const myVideoElement = useRef();
    const peerVideoElement = useRef();
    const chatInfo=useRef();
    const peerStream=useRef();
```

```
function startCall(){
    const peer=new SimplePeer({
      initiator:true,
      trickle:false,
      stream:stream,
    })

    peer.on('signal',(data)=>{
      socket.emit('calluser',{userToCall:chatInfo.current.userToCall,url:chatInfo.current.url,signalData:data,from:userId});
    });
    peer.on('stream',(stream)=>{
      if(peerVideoElement.current){
        peerVideoElement.current.srcObject=stream;
      }

      socket.on('callaccepted',(data)=>{
        peer.signal(data);
      })
    })
  }
```

```
function acceptCall(){
  setIsCallAccepted(true);
    const peer = new SimplePeer({
      initiator: false,
      trickle: false,
      stream: stream,
    });
    peer.on("signal", data => {
      socket.emit("acceptCall", { signal: data,to:chatInfo.current.userToCall})
    })

    peer.on("stream", stream => {
      peerVideoElement.current.srcObject = stream;
    });
    
    peer.signal(peerStream.current);
}
```

I expected it to just connect like how I read in the documentation and watched tutorial

Answer (score 5):

Please install this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/process

and include these in `index.js` at the very first line if you are using react.

You may need to move it to separate `./setup.js` file to follow create-react-app rules.

```
import * as process from 'process';

(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).process = process;
(window as any).Buffer = [];
```

if you are using angular, you could add these lines in polyfill.ts